# Flatten excel spreadsheet for ms sql server use

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I Found this spreadsheets online which I would like to flatten out and import into a MS SQL Server Database. The issue is that the spreadsheets have the same layout but is in a report format.

Any suggestions on how to flatten out this spreadsheet as there are to many sheets in one of this spreadsheets to do this manually. There are also a couple of different years of spreadsheets.

[Click here to open one of these spreadsheets](http://mfma.treasury.gov.za/Media_Releases/s71/1213/4th_2013/Documents/Excel/08.%20Consolidation%20of%20all%20municipalities%20-%204th%20Q%20S71%20-%2031%20July%202013.xls)

I want to be able to import this into my database and play with the numbers

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a staging area and importing each of the tabs into it's own specific table. This would give you the flexibility to work with the data initially. Then you would be able to easily flatten the data and transform it to your specifications. Also, this would be a good approach if you wanted to bring in only a couple of tabs in the beginning and flatten them. You could then extend the dataset by bringing in the tabs as you wanted to process them.